# Hide other emails while send email to multiple recepients or subscription list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, restsharp, mailgun

I have below `EmailViewModel`

```
public class EmailViewModel 
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select atleast one email id")]
  public string[] EmailID {get;set;}
  public SelectList Emails{get;set;}
  //Other properties
}
```

So with the above list of Emails, I have below part to add `to` `smtp` property into `RestSharp request`

```
foreach (var to in emodel.EmailID)
{
     request.AddParameter("to", to);
}
```

Now, the only problem is when I send email to multiple recipients, the other email ids will be visible in `to` list of each received recipient. I am aware that this can be done with `BCC`, but since, the design given to add email ids for the user contains only `to` field and thus all email id comes into one list. How can I go hiding these email id of other recipients? Should I add all the email id to the `bcc` property instead of `to` property or is there any other way to do this?

**Update**

This is how I execute the email request.

```
var resp = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Why don't you send one by one?

Comment: @FirstStep.. I feel it's time consuming..  I think I've go with that option now...

Comment: Time consuming as coding wise you mean or as execution wise?

Comment: execution wise @FirstStep...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't hide the other to addresses.

You either have to send them with BCC, or send one email per address.

Comment: Cool.. I have to go with one by one option.. and I feel I've to make it `async` task.. Well, I'll work on that.. Accepting answer in few mins.. Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 3):

There are only two things you can do. One is use BCC, but unless the recipient knows and trusts you it looks suspicious and weird. It also informs the recipients that the exact same email is going to other recipients, so they can tell that nothing about that email is personalized for them. That makes it less appealing.

The other option (probably preferable) is to send an individual email to each recipient.

Comment: Yea.. May be I've to choose option of sending one by one.. Thanks for your time and +1..